# How to import .tsx file into Angular14?

Tags: reactjs, angular

I am trying to embed React Components into Angular because I have written some react components only because it's using a React library. However, my main framework is still Angular12+.

I have this .tsx file `src/app/my-react-component.tsx`

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default function MyReact() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello My React Component!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and I want to import this from `src/app/app.component.ts`

```
import MyReact from './my-react-component';
```

Then, I see this error

```
Import error, can't find file:
./my-react-component
```

To try, I added     `"jsx": "react"` to `tsconfig.json`, but did not work, a solution from https://codebyz.com/embedding-react-components-in-angular-the-easy-way/

This is [stackblitz page](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ztk6fz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmy-react-component.tsx,angular.json), which you can see this error.

Anyone who has a victory on importing .tsx into Angular project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did everything right

1. specify `jsx: react` in `tsconfig`
2. create a wrapper with React rendering (with standalone directive it becomes much simpler btw)

It's just an error from Stackblitz because they have their own vision of typescript compilation.

Here is a link with the same code [from Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-bartik-28rycp?file=/src/app/my-react-component.tsx)